# themebuilder for kendo ui web

Tags: kendo-ui

I saw there is a themebuilder for kendo UI mobile. Is there one for there web products like grid? I could not find one on the website. I am looking to change the look of all the web widgets with one css file.

Comment: Kendo UI Theme Builder could be found on Demos: [http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html](http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KendoUI Web Theme Builder](http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html)

[KendoUI Web Theme Builder Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/themebuilder#using-the-themebuilder-on-your-own-pages)

It looks like you have to bookmark the theme builder and then open it on a page that has KendoUI controls on it.

Comment: yes its working now but earlier the builder was disabled for some reason. Thank you.

Comment: is it my idea or the bookmarkable widget is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

The kendo UI team has now fixed the theme builder for web. Just go to the theme builder section and select web it will launch a web tool that lets you theme your widgets.